# Find the two largest numbers

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the two maximum values out of ten user inputs.
I don't want to use any java pre-built methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoLargestNumber {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int counter = 0;
        int firstMax = 0;
        int secondMax = 0;

        while (counter <= 9) {
            System.out.println("Enter ten numbers: ");
            int number = input.nextInt();

            if (number > firstMax) {
                firstMax = number;
            }
            else if (number > secondMax && number != firstMax) {
                secondMax = number;
            }

            counter += 1;
        }

        System.out.printf("Largest numbers found: %d , %d", firstMax, secondMax);

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Above is the solution I provided which works fine, but I noticed that when I input ten number in ascending order the value of secondMax will be 0 as it doesn't meet the criteria of the while loop. Any ideas on how to implement something that overcome this issue?

Comment: I don't see any `for` loop.

Comment: You're already using pre-built methods ;) Why not enter the numbers first then work on them later? You don't currently do anything to `secondMax` if the first condition is true--you may want to reconsider that.

Comment: Don't you want to move `firstMax` to `secondMax` before overwriting it?

Comment: My hint is better :p :D

Comment: I meant 'while loop'

Comment: While assigning, 'firstMax = number'  you should  copy  firstMax to secondMax .( Use 'secondMax  = firstMax' before  'firstMax = number')

Comment: Folks: instead of coming right out and doing the work try guiding first, providing when necessary.

Comment: Lets pretend you want `4` numbers and they are `8,9,10,10.`  Is `firstMax 10` and `secondMax 10` or `firstMax 10` and `secondMax 9`?  What are the situations where `firstMax` and `secondMax` can be the same? If the numbers were `10, 10, 10, 10`?

Answer (score 0):

If were sorting an actual pile of objects based on size, and I wanted the two biggest I'd have three piles:

- Incoming item
- Largest item
- Second largest item

And anything else gets tossed in the incinerator.

If it's the first time I've looked at an item, I automatically know it's the biggest item. If it's the second time, it has to be in one of those two piles. I may need to shuffle the item from the largest pile to the second largest pile.

After that, any additional items may displace one of those. If it displaces the largest, then we have to shuffle the largest pile item down to the second largest pile.

Your code doesn't handle those first two special cases, except by assuming they're bigger than zero. It also doesn't handle shunting the previously largest down to the second largest pile in the event we've found a new largest.

If you correct these issues your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Two basic things to consider:

- if you find a number larger than or equal to `firstMax`, assign `firstMax` to `secondMax` and then assign the number to `firstMax` since the previous `firstMax` is now the second largest number.
- Otherwise, simply test `secondMax` against the entered number and assign as appropriate.

Other ideas.

- decide what your limits are.  Assign `firstMax` and `secondMax` the **lowest** numbers that could be entered so they can be replaced if need be.  This could be `Integer.MIN_VALUE` for all numbers allowed or `0` for just numbers >= 0.
- you could also initialize them to a separate initial input from the terminal.
- And what about the largest number entered multiple times? Does that mean that `firstMax` and `secondMax` share the same value?  If not, then what is the `secondMax` assigned when all the values are the same?

And it is bad practice to close the scanner when it is taking input from the terminal.  If you need to use it again within the same program you won't be able to reopen the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Dont use else and add a buffer that compares the last number too.
then at the end, compare the last number, this way you meake sure that always works

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int counter = 0;
    int firstMax = 0;
    int secondMax = 0;
    int number = 0;
    int prevNumber = 0;

    while (counter <= 9) {        
        number = input.nextInt();
        
        if (number > firstMax) {
            firstMax = number;
        }
        if (prevNumber > secondMax && prevNumber < firstMax) {
            secondMax = prevNumber;
        }
       
        prevNumber = number;
        counter++;
    }
    if (number > secondMax && number < firstMax) {
        secondMax = number;
    }

    System.out.printf("Largest numbers found: %d , %d", firstMax, secondMax);

    input.close();
}
```